# Color today date on calendar

Tags: android, colors, android-drawable, android-calendar

I have an example of Calendar in android. In the beginning all dates have light gray background, only today date have blue background. When I press another date, it turns into blue. I want that today date keeps dark gray background when I press another date. How can I do this?

**Part of CalendarAdapter.java**

```
if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {  //Turns today date into blue when started
        setSelected(v);
   previousView = v;
  } else {
   v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
  }
```

**list_item_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
      android:drawable="@drawable/calendar_cel_selectl"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item 
      android:drawable="@drawable/calendar_cel_selectl"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item  
      android:drawable="@drawable/calendar_cell" />
</selector>
```

Comment: don't setSelected it, as the selection will change. You need to give it a different background altogether

Comment: SetSelected is using when I launch calendar, for selecting today date, and turns it into blue. I want that today date keeps different color from another days

Comment: yes. see my previous comment.